# Which command should I use in the subscription confirmation button link to rewrite the tag?

Tags: email, tags, command

Command for subscribing a contact for emailing + assigning a tag in the email button

Answer (score 0):

The command to sign up a customer for emailing + adding a tag is $opt-in: tag_name$